# Any way to restrict access to heroku application from specific Github-pages repository?

Tags: git, github, heroku, github-pages, cors-anywhere

I have a repository with an associated `github-pages` branch which is hosted at `https://myusername.github.io/repo-name`

The `gh-pages` application needs a cors proxy to run, which I'm doing by forking [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) and deploying an instance to heroku.

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to only allow traffic coming from my repository's `gh-pages` branch to the heroku proxy.

Is there any way to achieve this?

The interim solution I have is to add the proxy as a CI/CD step but this still means someone could look at the network traffic in chrome and see what the proxy being used is.